# Highcharts marker alignment not matched with Axis gridlines

Tags: javascript, highcharts, lineseries

[image]

options passed like below:

```
var chartOptions = {
                        chart: {
                            backgroundColor: 'white',
                            type:'line'
                        },
                        title: { 
                            text:null
                        },
                        xAxis: {
                            gridLineWidth:0.5,
                            gridLineColor:'#e1e1e1',
                            tickInterval:intervalPeriod,
                            tickWidth: 0,
                            type: 'datetime',
                            dateTimeLabelFormats: dateTimeLabelFormats
                        },  
                        yAxis: {
                            gridLineWidth:0.5,
                            gridLineColor:'#e1e1e1',
                            allowDecimals:false,
                            tickAmount: 5,
                            title: {
                                text: null
                            }
                        },
                        tooltip:{
                            shared:true,
                            xDateFormat:'%e  %b, %Y',
                            crosshairs:true
                        }
                }
```

Comment: Have a look at http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series%3Cline%3E.pointPlacement

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the same value for `tickInterval` and `pointInterval` in order to display tick synced with series' points. When points have irregular intervals, then you can use `tickPositions` array.

API Reference:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickInterval
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.pointInterval
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickPositions

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/zycwaexa/ - using the same `tickInterval` and `pointInterval`
http://jsfiddle.net/z7pnwtrs/ - using `tickPositions`